# Providing measurement data (from serial port) to other classes?

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures

I've got a device which is connected via a virtual COM port. This device sends measuring data every 100ms. There are multiple channels which can be individually (de)activated, which influences which data / which channels are sent.

At the moment, I provide the data via an event of type `Dictionary<string, double>`. The string is the name of the channel, double is the value. The first "channel" is a timestamp from the device. Classes that need the data simply subscribe to the event.

The data is needed for a Chart (to be displayed in the MainWindow) and some other classes which occasionally need the last n values to perform several checks (min/max/average...).

Of course, I feel that firing an event roughly every 100ms is a very ineffective way of providing the measurement data to other parts of the application (especially redrawing the chart). Would [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx) be a good alternative to this?

If so, How would DataTable behave for "unspecified" values, e.g. when for a given timestamp a channel was not activated (and thus, not sent by the device), so there are "holes" in the data? To visualize, it might look like this

```
    Time  |  Ch1  |  Ch2  |  Ch3  | ...
    ------+-------+-------+-------+
       0  |  34   |       |       |
       1  |  35   |       |       |
       2  |  36   |       |       |
       3  |  35   |       |  23   |
       4  |  36   |  11   |  26   |
       5  |  37   |  13   |  26   |
       6  |       |  14   |  21   |
       7  |       |  13   |  25   |
       8  |       |  16   |       |
       9  |       |  14   |       |
      10  |       |  22   |       |
      11  |       |  24   |       |
      12  |       |  24   |  45   |
      13  |  37   |  27   |  44   |
      14  |  36   |       |  46   |
      15  |  35   |       |       |
      16  |  33   |       |       |
      17  |  32   |  30   |       |
      18  |  23   |  32   |       |
```

What other alternatives are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, at time 5 the value from channel 1 was 37. At time 6, no value was reported for channel 1. You have three choices:

1. Assign it some default value, or perhaps a random value.
2. Assume that the value hasn't changed from the previous reading.
3. Write code that takes the lack of a value there into account, and acts accordingly.

Option 1 isn't particularly useful, although if you gave it a default value that wouldn't ever be seen in normal processing, then you could at least see that no value was reported during that time period.

Option 3 really just pushed the responsibility for handling the problem on to the next guy in line. It does have the advantage, though, of keeping the data pure: you don't have a false indication that some data actually came in during that period.

Option 2 can be applied either at data collection time, or at data processing time. My preference is to handle it at processing time. That is, the data table would contain no value for the missing channels in any time period. Each method that processes the data can then determine how to handle it.

That said, I would caution against using a data table for this. I don't know if your code is multi-threaded, but if it is then you run into concurrency issues with one thread trying to update the table while others are trying to read it.

I would suggest instead an approach that has several different classes subscribing to the update event. Each event handler gets the event and does its own processing of each event, and keeps its own copy of just the data that it's interested in. That way, each individual component can handle the missing data point case in the best way for that particular situation.

An event every 100 ms isn't going to put a heavy load on the system, unless you're doing a lot of heavy duty processing of those events.

For the graph updater, I probably would have it updating on a timer. Say, once a second or once every 500 ms. The graphing class would maintain its own list of data, probably protected by a lock, which it populates from the event data passed to it. When the timer fires to update the graph, the code locks the list so that it won't be updated, draws the graph, and then unlocks the list.

For min/max/average calculation, again you'd maintain your own list of recent items and update the calculations as each item comes in. Maintaining a running min/max/average from the most recent `n` items is a pretty standard technique that requires very little processing.

Doing things this way probably requires a larger memory footprint, but it shouldn't be huge. In fact, when compared to the per-row overhead of a data table, it might even be cheaper. The benefit is that each class maintains just the data it needs in exactly the format best suited for that class's functionality.

I used this technique in a web crawler application I wrote many years ago, and it worked quite well. Each class was notified of each document that was downloaded, along with stats (how long it took, how large it was, etc.), and each class maintained displays on the screen to keep me informed of how the crawler was working. The crawler was downloading on the order of 15 documents per second, so I was firing events at a rate of about one every 66 ms, and the machine had no problem keeping up with that.

Comment: Thanks, especially for mentioning updating the chart via a timer. This is most likely the most expensive operation, and doing it every 100ms makes no sense indeed!